# Cannot find eclipse/plugins folder for Eclipse Mars on Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I'm trying to install eclipse to my Ubuntu virtual machine for hadoop development. After I downloaded Eclipse Mars and installed it by the installer, I couldn't find the plugin folder it uses. I looked up online and checked many threads. People seem to have the plugin folder at `/usr/share/eclipse/plugins` or `/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins` while I could find none. Eclipse was installed all by default location.

I looked up my file system and found several "candidates" that I guess may be the folder I was looking for:

`~/.p2/pool/plugins` I haven't seen this folder anywhere before

```
bitnami@linux:~/.p2/pool/plugins$ ll
total 188652
drwxrwxr-x 17 bitnami bitnami    45056 Nov 21 15:50 .
drwxrwxr-x  4 bitnami bitnami     4096 Nov 21 16:24 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 bitnami bitnami   261508 Nov 21 15:19 ch.qos.logback.classic_1.0.7.v20121108-1250.jar
-rw-rw-r--  1 bitnami bitnami   389365 Nov 21 15:19 ch.qos.logback.core_1.0.7.v20121108-1250.jar
-rw-rw-r--  1 bitnami bitnami    10642 Nov 21 15:19 ch.qos.logback.slf4j_1.0.7.v201505121915.jar
-rw-rw-r--  1 bitnami bitnami   211185 Nov 21 15:19 com.google.gson_2.2.4.v201311231704.jar
-rw-rw-r--  1 bitnami bitnami  2263565 Nov 21 15:19 com.google.guava_15.0.0.v201403281430.jar
-rw-rw-r--  1 bitnami bitnami   520624 Nov 21 15:19 com.google.inject_3.0.0.v201312141243.jar
-rw-rw-r--  1 bitnami bitnami    41887 Nov 21 15:19 com.google.inject.multibindings_3.0.0.v201402270930.jar
-rw-rw-r--  1 bitnami bitnami    53029 Nov 21 15:19 com.gradleware.tooling.client_0.6.1.v201509101146.jar
-rw-rw-r--  1 bitnami bitnami   123829 Nov 21 15:19 com.gradleware.tooling.model_0.6.1.v201509101146.jar
-rw-rw-r--  1 bitnami bitnami    25621 Nov 21 15:19 com.gradleware.tooling.utils_0.6.1.v201509101146.jar
```

The artifact.xml locates in `~/.p2/pool/`

```
bitnami@linux:~/.p2/pool$ ll
total 200
drwxrwxr-x  4 bitnami bitnami   4096 Nov 21 16:24 .
drwxrwxr-x  6 bitnami bitnami   4096 Nov 21 16:24 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 bitnami bitnami 135114 Nov 21 15:21 artifacts.xml
drwxrwxr-x 70 bitnami bitnami  12288 Nov 21 15:20 features
drwxrwxr-x 17 bitnami bitnami  45056 Nov 21 15:50 plugins
```

Or `~/workspace/.metadata/.plugins`

```
bitnami@linux:~/workspace/.metadata/.plugins$ ll
total 23096
drwxrwxr-x 19 bitnami bitnami     4096 Nov 21 16:22 .
drwxrwxr-x  4 bitnami bitnami     4096 Nov 21 15:42 ..
-rw-r-----  1 bitnami bitnami 23568786 Nov 21 16:22 hadoop-0.22.0-eclipse-plugin.jar
drwxrwxr-x  5 bitnami bitnami     4096 Nov 21 15:49 org.eclipse.core.resources
drwxrwxr-x  3 bitnami bitnami     4096 Nov 21 15:21 org.eclipse.core.runtime
drwxrwxr-x  2 bitnami bitnami     4096 Nov 21 16:10 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt
drwxrwxr-x  2 bitnami bitnami     4096 Nov 21 15:26 org.eclipse.e4.workbench
drwxrwxr-x  2 bitnami bitnami     4096 Nov 21 16:10 org.eclipse.emf.common.ui
drwxrwxr-x  4 bitnami bitnami     4096 Nov 21 15:21 org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.ui
drwxrwxr-x  2 bitnami bitnami     4096 Nov 21 15:49 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui
drwxrwxr-x  2 bitnami bitnami     4096 Nov 21 15:49 org.eclipse.jdt.core
drwxrwxr-x  2 bitnami bitnami     4096 Nov 21 15:49 org.eclipse.jdt.ui
drwxrwxr-x  2 bitnami bitnami     4096 Nov 21 15:21 org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration
drwxrwxr-x  2 bitnami bitnami     4096 Nov 21 15:21 org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.core
drwxrwxr-x  3 bitnami bitnami     4096 Nov 21 15:21 org.eclipse.mylyn.context.core
drwxrwxr-x  2 bitnami bitnami     4096 Nov 21 15:21 org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui
```

I put the hadoop plugin jar for eclipse in these 2 folders but neither worked out.

I checked my eclipse.ini and I think these lines might be relevant:

```
-startup
../../../.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
../../../.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-install
/home/bitnami/eclipse/java-mars/eclipse
-vm
/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_40/jre/bin
```

This is the first time I used Eclipse on Ubuntu. Please kindly point me to the right direction. Appreciate you suggestions!!

Comment: What is in `/home/bitnami/eclipse/java-mars/eclipse`?

Comment: @greg-449 Folders: configuration  dropins  readme; Files: eclipse  eclipse.ini  icon.xpm

Answer (score 1):

Don't look for the plugin folder, just put your jar in the eclipse/dropins folder.

Your real question seems to be:  "How can install software in my eclipse environment when this is not possible through the software updates dialog?**"

With older eclipse version the answer was the plugins folder you are looking for, now at least from juno, you are given the dropins folder, just put your jar there or have a look at the documentation for more complex packaging.

Referring specifically to hadoop, this approach [had been reported working](http://blog.csdn.net/ansonxing168/article/details/16365011) since juno and since 2013.

Source:  eclipse mars documentation > Platform Plug-in Developer Guide > Reference > Other reference information >
[The dropins folder and supported file layouts](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/p2_dropins_format.html)

> The Eclipse platform ships with a default watched directory called
>   dropins. The dropins folder is configured to be scanned during
>   startup. Thus the dropins folder can be used much like the plugins
>   directory was used in the past.

** the documentation page reports two other way to install software, p2 tools and APIs, but they seems not relevant to your question

Comment: Under MacOS X , install Eclipse by EclipseInstaller , I find dropins foler /Users/xxxx/eclipse/jee-mars2/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/dropins.

Comment: And where is the eclipse/dropins folder?

Comment: eclipse is the root folder of you installation, where eclipse.exe resides.
dropins is one of its first level subfolder, it was this way in mars edition as the link in the answer says and it is the same now in eclipse 2019-09 (see https://help.eclipse.org/2019-09/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/p2_dropins_format.html, verified on my Windows installations but I do not expect anything different on other platforms)